# unable to set web inspector breakpoints after upgrade to Safari 7.0.4, both local and remote

Tags: ios, debugging, mobile-safari, remote-debugging

After an upgrade to OSX 10.9.3 (13D65) and Safari 7.0.4 (9537.76.4), I am unable to set breakpoints in my cordova app using the Safari web inspector.  Enabled breakpoints appear as dark grey, disabled as a lighter grey. "debugger" statements are ignored.  The behavior is the same on either the simulator (iOS 7.1 11D167) or a physical device (iOS 7.1.1 11D201). The mobile app does show up under the Develop menu (iPad Simulator or xxx iPad).  I can inspect the DOM.  I tried the solutions suggested in this problem:  [Why is Web Inspector showing me "no inspectable applications"?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21844851/why-is-web-inspector-showing-me-no-inspectable-applications), and this [Why Safari shows "No Inspectable Applications" during remote debugging with iOS 6 device?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16999186/why-safari-shows-no-inspectable-applications-during-remote-debugging-with-ios?rq=1).

The mobile app is compiled locally.  It is debuggable on a second machine running the same versions of OSX & Safari, but I don't have access to that machine full time.  Both machines have the same developer profiles and certificates (with private keys). How can I diagnose this??  Thank you for your help.

Answer (score 10):

turns out that the issue was "Stop-plugins to save power" was enabled under Safari / Preferences (Advanced Tab). That disabled the ability to set a breakpoint.  I don't recall setting that, but I didn't see anything indicating that the upgrade set that preference.

Comment: Thank you for figuring that out! I was not even seeing an option to remote debug any devices anymore and clearing that option did the trick (along with a restart of Safari). Was pulling the hair out of my head trying to figure out what I was not doing correctly... :)

Comment: Yup, this fixed it for me too. Thanks for the protip :)

Comment: @hashchange Thanks for choosing that username. I happened to be experiencing this issue but breakpoints worked except those inside my hashchange event handler. Had you chosen any other name, I doubt I'd have found this solution.

Comment: @Walf Lovely - and I can add "Impersonating a tag" to my life achievements now. ;) Cheers!

Answer (score 2):

It is also necessary to place your breakpoints on lines containing executable code.

Breakpoints on blank lines between other lines of code are ignored.

Comment: Please give an example